# How to only trigger mouse move in border area of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All:

I am trying to implement a resizing function(drag the border of a DIV to resize it), but the trigger event is really hard to find.

Say I only want a single DIV, instead set Border area element inside it, I would like find a way to set event listener on that DIV element, I know SVG can do that by setting pointer-events to stroke, but I have no idea how to do this on HTML element.

```
<style>
    #resize {
        border:solid black 5px;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:block;
/* I do not know what to set here to make only border can respond to mouse action */
    }
</style>

<div id="resize"></div>

<script>

    $("#resize").on("mousemove", function(){
        if(isMouseDown) {
            // drag to resize logic here
        }
    })

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: You could check if a mouse coordinate is close to a border. E.g. if you want to resize horizontally and your `div` is `100px` wide, you could check if the `x` coordinate is between `99` and `101`. Of course, you could set better thresholds.

Comment: @Kuan Please respond to the answers posted by me.

Answer (score 1):

borders are not elements so you can't bind to them, but you can use offset() and outerWidth() and check is they are the same as the mouse position.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you want only one div, but maybe you could place one above other and use bottom div as border. I've made fiddle to illustrate this behaviour, check console.log.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apeuLbjx/)

```
.outside {

    height:60px;

    width:60px;

    background:black;

    position:relative;

    z-index: 30;

}

.inside {

    background: yellow;

    height:50px;

    width:50px;

    position: absolute;

    top:12px;

    left: 13px;

    z-index:999;

}
```

and html

```
<div class="outside"></div>
<div class="inside"></div>
```

and js

```
$(".outside").on("mousemove", function () {
    console.log('im above outer element');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this smart idea( I think I may need to rethink about  giving up single DIV solution). But I kinda wondering if there is a simple way to determine which direction I move the mouse in from?

Comment: try to use jquery position() on element and compare to mousemove coordinates, for working with coordinates check http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/ - the bottom example

Comment: Css rule shud be `.outside`

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to make the border a parent div

```
<div id="resize">
    <div id="innerpart">
    </div>
</div>
```

you can see a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/s5gz9w73/1/

Comment: Thanks for solution, but I kinda wondering if there is a simple way to determine which direction I move the mouse in from?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution after a tricky workaround —

Collect the coordinates of border using simple geometrical calculations.

```
Set of Border Coordinates = Set of (Border + Content) Coordinates - Set of Content Coordinates
```

You can create an array of border coordinates as follows:

```
var y_offset = $("#resize").offset().top;
var x_offset = $("#resize").offset().left;

var y_outer = y_offset + $("#resize").height() + (2 * 5) - 1;
var x_outer = x_offset + $("#resize").width() + (2 * 5) - 1;

var i, j, pos, outer_size;
var outer_div_coord = [];
pos = 0;

for(i = x_offset; i <= x_outer; i++){
  for(j = y_offset; j <= y_outer; j++){
    outer_div_coord[pos++] = i + "," + j;
  }
}
outer_size = pos;

var inner_div_coord = [];
pos = 0;

for(i = x_offset + 5; i <= x_outer - 5; i++){
  for(j = y_offset + 5; j <= y_outer - 5; j++){
    inner_div_coord[pos++] = i + "," + j;
  }
}

var border_coord = [];
pos = 0;

for(i = 0; i < outer_size; i++){
  if(inner_div_coord.indexOf(outer_div_coord[i]) == -1){
    border_coord[pos] = outer_div_coord[i];
    pos++;
  }
}
```

Then by using `.mousemove(function(e){});` handler, you can check whether the "`e.clientX`,`e.clientY`" belongs to `border_coord[]` as follows:

```
$("#resize").mousemove(function(e){
  cursor_coord = e.clientX + "," + e.clientY;
  if(border_coord.indexOf(cursor_coord) > -1)
    console.log("on border");
});
```

Here's a working [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/jiyina/1/edit?console,output).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make use of the css `resize: both;` property and detect change in size of `#resize` using jQuery?

Here's a proposal:

```js
var h = 100;
var w = 100;
var ctr = 0;
$("#resize").mouseup(function(){
  if($(this).height() != h || $(this).width() != w){
    ctr++;
    $("pre").text("resized "+ctr);
    h = $(this).height();
    w = $(this).width();
  }
});
```

```css
#resize {
  border: solid black 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resize"></div>
<pre>resized 0</pre>
```

Although, alot depends on what are you exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: What I really want to do is make a table with fixed total width but adjustable columns inside. Could you show me an example how to use your code snippet?

Comment: However your question says something totally different. Don't think the other solution posted by me should be accepted as an answer as per the question description? :) Please do accept it if you think so. Coming back to your requirement, are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsbin.com/wocave/1/edit?output). If that's the case I think this answer is helpful and deserves a +1. ;)